# Instantiating array after declaring results in compile error "Illegal start of expression, not a statement, ; expected"

Tags: java, arrays

I'm receiving a compilation error with netbeans IDE when writing this two-dimensional int array, this is how I'm initializing it:

```
private int[][] anArray;
```

This next part is declared in a method later on in the file.

```
anArray = {{15501, 1}, {215, 3}, {1693, 72}};
```

With NetBeans IDE I receive a compilation error

> Illegal start of expression, not a statement, ; expected

Comment: In the future questions, please describe the actual problem in the title instead of using an overly generic and completely useless phrase which doesn't tell *anything* about the concrete problem such as "what's wrong with this code?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
anArray = new int[][] {{15501, 1}, {215, 3}, {1693, 72}};
```

Arrays are instantiated like objects, so you need to use `new` and the array type.

If you do direct instantiation in the same line as the variable identifier, this will work:

```
int[][] anArray = {{15501, 1}, {215, 3}, {1693, 72}};
```

Comment: The `new` is unnecessary when there's direct instantiation.

Comment: @BalusC oh didn't know that! Add this to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
private int[][] anArray = { { 15501, 1 }, { 215, 3 }, { 1693, 72 } };
```

Or you want to initialize it later you can use `new` operator

```
anArray = new int[][] { { 15501, 1 }, { 215, 3 }, { 1693, 72 } };
```